# Origine de l'expression "demi-" (demi-millier, demi-douzaine)

Tags: expressions

Il est souvent employé la forme **demi** - *quelque-chose* comme:

- Une demi-douzaine
- Un demi-millier

D’où provient cette expression faisant préférer se référer a un calcul plutôt qu'a la valeur ? Plus simplement, pourquoi va t-on dire "une demie-douzaine" au lieu de "six" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'usage courant d'une langue est qu'on n'utilise pas tous les chiffres et les nombres à sa disposition. Ça se fait par pallier irrégulier.

Il n'y a aucune règle derrière, c'est juste une habitude qui vient de l'usage. La facilité de prononciation y participe également j'imagine : par exemple on utilise régulièrement une dizaine, une douzaine, une vingtaine, trentaine, quarantaine, cinquantaine, soixantaine, centaine, millier, million.

Alors que les intermédiaires s'utilisent plus rarement, à moins d'être dans un contexte nécessitant de la précision.

Autre exemple j'ai personnellement tendance à utiliser régulièrement les nombres 25 et 75 et pas leurs voisins immédiats, tout simplement à cause de leur position mathématique (1/4 et 3/4).

Donc tout ça pour dire que certaines nombres bénéficient d'un traitement de faveur, et qu'on a tendance à leur ajouter des multiples et des diviseurs plutôt que d'utiliser l'infinie possibilité des nombres existants.

Answer (score 0):

Alors que 6 et 500 ne peuvent être utilisés que comme des valeurs exactes, demi préserve le caractère approximatif des expressions citées.

Une douzaine, c'est probablement douze, mais peut-être onze ou treize suivant le contexte.   Une demi-douzaine, c'est donc le plus souvent six mais cinq ou sept ne sont pas complètement exclus.

De la même manière, un millier, ce n'est n'est pas exactement 1000 et un demi-millier, ce n'est pas exactement 500.

Comment: Effectivement mais ça ne donne pas d’idée compte à l’origine historique de cette habitude ☺

Comment: @Fauve Diviser un tout par deux n'est pas une habitude particulière mais un concept assez universel. L'expression demi-douzaine date au moins du XVème siècle mais est probablement beaucoup plus ancienne, a rapprocher de la numération duodécimale qui a longtemps coexisté avec la décimale jusqu'à ce que le système métrique se soit imposé.

Answer (score 0):

XIe siècle, comme adjectif ; XIIe siècle, substantif féminin, « moitié » ; XVIIe siècle, substantif masculin. Du latin populaire *dimedius, « demi », réfection, d'après medius, « central, intermédiaire, participant à deux choses » (voir Mi), du latin classique dimidius, « demi ».

SOURCE : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/demi

Answer (score 0):

Pour la même raison qu'on préfère dire 1 tonne et demie, ou 1 année et demi. 
On reste dans le contexte d'unité dont on parle.

Si les oeufs sont vendus par douzaine, on demande une demi-douzaine, ça veut dire un demi-carton. Il est plus vite de diviser à deux une unité connue que de compter les oeufs individuels.

Le mot même provient [du mot latin classique 'medium' (milieu)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demi),  [qui devient 'demedius', puis 'dimidius' en latin vulgaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_vulgaire#Attestation_des_changements) et se contracte à'demi'.