# Chiffrer en -aine ajoute-t-il une idée d'approximation ?

Tags: expressions, nombres

Lorsqu'on utilise dizaine au lieu de dix, ou douzaine au lieu de douze (voire demi-douzaine au lieu de six), souhaite-t-on indiquer une idée d'approximation ?
Une [reponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9263/11921) à la question [Origine de l'expression "demi-" (demi-millier, demi-douzaine)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9257/origine-de-lexpression-demi-demi-millier-demi-douzaine) semble l'indiquer, mais cette réponse n'est pas claire et semble n'être que le sentiment personnel de l'auteur.

D'ailleurs, lorsqu'au marché on achète une douzaine d'huîtres, on est bien certain d'en obtenir douze.

Comment: Quoique, généralement, on en obtienne 13!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La notion d'approximation est présente mais pas absolue dans l'utilisation de dizaine, voir le dictionnaire de l'Académie :

> XIVe siècle. Dérivé de dix, sur le modèle de centaine.
>   ☆1. MATH. Groupe de dix unités. Dix dizaines forment une centaine. Décomposer un nombre selon les centaines, les dizaines. Compter par dizaines.
>   ☆2. Réunion de personnes, assemblage de choses de même nature par nombre de dix ; de l'ordre de dix. Assembler par dizaine. Nous étions une bonne dizaine, au moins dix. Il reviendra dans une dizaine de jours, dans dix jours environ.
>   RELIG. CATHOL. Dizaine de chapelet, suite de dix grains d'un chapelet, séparée des autres suites par un grain plus gros. Par méton. Prière composée de dix Ave et d'un Pater. Dire une dizaine de chapelet.

Answer (score 4):

Dans le langage courant moderne il s'agit d'une approximation:

> Il y avait une dizaine d'hommes devant le bar.

Signifie qu'il y avait environ dix hommes devant le bar. On peut rajouter des ajdectifs pour préciser: par exemple "une petite dizaine" désigne souvent un nombre entre sept et neuf.

En ce qui concerne les huitres (ou les oeufs), il s'agit d'une expression figée qui a gardé le sens plus ancien de nombre exact.

On trouve aussi ces expressions pour parler d'un nombre de jours, dans ce cas la durée est toujours erronée: une huitaine c'est une semaine (qui fait en réalité sept jours), une quinzaine c'en est deux (qui en font quatorze).

En résumé, il est possible d'utiliser ces expressions pour parler d'un nombre précis, mais dans ce cas on prend le risque d'être mal compris.